# Proving $\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \sim (\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\setminus \{\emptyset\})$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Prove: $\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \sim (\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\setminus \{\emptyset\})$

My attempt:

One side is obvious since $\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \supset (\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\setminus \{\emptyset\})$ so $|\mathcal P(\mathbb N)| > |(\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\setminus \{\emptyset\})|$ so we know there's an injective function from the RHS to LHS.

For the other side, define $f$ to be:

$$ f(X)=\begin{cases}
\{1\} &,X=\emptyset \\
\{n+1\} &, X=\{n\} \\
X &, else
 \end{cases} $$

We just performed a linear operation on all sets $X=\{n\}$ otherwise the function is the identity, therefore it's injective.

From CSB we can conclude that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N) \sim (\mathcal P(\mathbb N)\setminus \{\emptyset\})$

Is that alright?

Comment: It is OK, but why refer to CSB when you can exhibit a bijection?

Comment: @AndréNicolas haven't thought about that, is the explanation for $f$ being onto the same?

Comment: Yes, the mapping is a bijection, the old Hilbert infinite hotel trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is alright. You can do it also like this:

$$\newcommand{\PP}{\mathcal{P}}
\Big|\PP(\mathbb{N})\Big| 
= \Big|\PP(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\})\Big|
= \Bigg|\Big\{A \cup \{0\}: A \in \PP\big(\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}\big)\Big\}\Bigg|
\leq \Big|\PP(\mathbb{N})\setminus\{\varnothing\}\Big|
\leq \Big|\PP(\mathbb{N})\Big|.$$

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$